# Show that The Hausdorff Measure is a Measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove that the Hausdorff measure is, in fact, a measure.

**Definition.** $\mu$ is a *measure* on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ if $\mu$ assigns a non-negative number (possibly $\infty$), to each subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that

- $\mu(\emptyset)=0$;
- $\mu(S)\leq\mu(T)$ if $S\subseteq T$;
- if $S_{1},S_{2},\ldots$ is a countable or finite sequence of sets, then $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}S_{i}\right)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(S_{i})$ with equality if $S_{i}$ are disjoint Borel sets.

We call $\mu(S)$ the *measure* of $S$.

**Definition.** Suppose $F\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $s\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$. For $\delta>0$, consider all $\delta$-covers of $F$ and minimise the sum of the $s$th powers of the diameters. As $\delta\to0$, the class of permissible covers of $F$ is reduced. So $$\mathcal{H}_{\delta}^{s}(F)=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|U_{i}|^{s}:\{U_{i}\} \text{ is a } \delta \text{-cover of } F\right\}$$ increases and so approaches a limit. The *$s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure* $$\mathcal{H}^{s}(F)=\lim_{\delta\to0}\mathcal{H}_{\delta}^{s}(F)$$ exists for any $F\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ although it can be, and often is, either $0$ of $\infty$.

**What I've done:** Obviously $\mathcal{H}^{s}(\emptyset)=0$, and it is intuitive that if $E\subseteq F$, then $\mathcal{H}^{s}(E)\leqslant\mathcal{H}^{s}(F)$. What I am not sure how to do it show that $$\mathcal{H}^{s}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_{i}\right)\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}^{s}(F_{i})$$ with equality if $\{F{i}\}$ are disjoint Borel sets.

Comment: In your definition of a measure, do you really want to define $\mu$ on *each* subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$? Or perhaps only on Borel subsets?

Comment: Theorem 2.19 here (https://books.google.de/books?id=R0o8DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=topological+borel+outer+measure+distance&source=bl&ots=zmA0lu1Lmf&sig=rGZ0c_VLmNIeuiAKGDF1HDQjrkc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjctMDtr_zUAhUKPFAKHQUkBRkQ6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=topological%20borel%20outer%20measure%20distance&f=false) might be helpful.

Comment: @LeeMosher only Borel subsets are necessary, but it is my understanding that they are well-defined on all subsets.

Comment: @PhoemueX I will have a read through. Thank you.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not the case that measures are well-defined on all subsets. That's not even true for the standard Lebesgue measure on the real line (assuming the axiom of choice).

Comment: Oh, well in that case I suppose Borel sets will have to do :)

Comment: @LeeMosher: That depends. If you only assume (as the OP does) that the measure be countably **subadditive**, you can define the measure for all subsets. Usually, this is then called an **outer measure**. Nevertheless, some authors (notably Evans and Gariepy) call this a measure. Note that the OP only requires the countable **additivity** for Borel sets.

Comment: @PhoemueX, I have been trying to do this problem as well (only for Borel subsets - I don't know if that's what OP is doing?) Anyway, I can't access the book that you posted for some reason, is there other material you know about or some pointers you can get me? Thanks.